# Why Deep Adaptive Input Normalization (DAIN) normalizes time series data accross rows?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, data-science, normalization, preprocessor

The [DAIN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07892.pdf) describes how a network learns to normalize time series data by itself, [here](https://github.com/passalis/dain/blob/master/dain.py) is how the authors implemented it. The code leads me to think that normalization is happening across rows, not columns. Can anyone explain why it is implemented that way? Because I always thought that one normalizes time series only across columns to keep each feature's true information.

Here is the piece the does normalization:

````
```python
class DAIN_Layer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mode='adaptive_avg', mean_lr=0.00001, gate_lr=0.001, scale_lr=0.00001, input_dim=144):
        super(DAIN_Layer, self).__init__()
        print("Mode = ", mode)

        self.mode = mode
        self.mean_lr = mean_lr
        self.gate_lr = gate_lr
        self.scale_lr = scale_lr

        # Parameters for adaptive average
        self.mean_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim, bias=False)
        self.mean_layer.weight.data = torch.FloatTensor(data=np.eye(input_dim, input_dim))

        # Parameters for adaptive std
        self.scaling_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim, bias=False)
        self.scaling_layer.weight.data = torch.FloatTensor(data=np.eye(input_dim, input_dim))

        # Parameters for adaptive scaling
        self.gating_layer = nn.Linear(input_dim, input_dim)

        self.eps = 1e-8

    def forward(self, x):
        # Expecting  (n_samples, dim,  n_feature_vectors)

        # Nothing to normalize
        if self.mode == None:
            pass

        # Do simple average normalization
        elif self.mode == 'avg':
            avg = torch.mean(x, 2)
            avg = avg.resize(avg.size(0), avg.size(1), 1)
            x = x - avg

        # Perform only the first step (adaptive averaging)
        elif self.mode == 'adaptive_avg':
            avg = torch.mean(x, 2)
            adaptive_avg = self.mean_layer(avg)
            adaptive_avg = adaptive_avg.resize(adaptive_avg.size(0), adaptive_avg.size(1), 1)
            x = x - adaptive_avg

        # Perform the first + second step (adaptive averaging + adaptive scaling )
        elif self.mode == 'adaptive_scale':

            # Step 1:
            avg = torch.mean(x, 2)
            adaptive_avg = self.mean_layer(avg)
            adaptive_avg = adaptive_avg.resize(adaptive_avg.size(0), adaptive_avg.size(1), 1)
            x = x - adaptive_avg

            # Step 2:
            std = torch.mean(x ** 2, 2)
            std = torch.sqrt(std + self.eps)
            adaptive_std = self.scaling_layer(std)
            adaptive_std[adaptive_std <= self.eps] = 1

            adaptive_std = adaptive_std.resize(adaptive_std.size(0), adaptive_std.size(1), 1)
            x = x / (adaptive_std)

        elif self.mode == 'full':

            # Step 1:
            avg = torch.mean(x, 2)
            adaptive_avg = self.mean_layer(avg)
            adaptive_avg = adaptive_avg.resize(adaptive_avg.size(0), adaptive_avg.size(1), 1)
            x = x - adaptive_avg

            # # Step 2:
            std = torch.mean(x ** 2, 2)
            std = torch.sqrt(std + self.eps)
            adaptive_std = self.scaling_layer(std)
            adaptive_std[adaptive_std <= self.eps] = 1

            adaptive_std = adaptive_std.resize(adaptive_std.size(0), adaptive_std.size(1), 1)
            x = x / adaptive_std

            # Step 3: 
            avg = torch.mean(x, 2)
            gate = F.sigmoid(self.gating_layer(avg))
            gate = gate.resize(gate.size(0), gate.size(1), 1)
            x = x * gate

        else:
            assert False

        return x
```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Comment: The question is about deep learning technique, which should be okay. Can you please explain in more detail why this question got closed?

Comment: Please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Note says, "If you want to use this tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on Computer Science, Cross Validated, Data Science, or Artificial Intelligence instead. Otherwise you're probably off-topic". My question DIRECTLY concerns implementation and I put the link to that implementation in the question. The question is literally about machine learning and deep learning. Please, re-open the question.

Comment: If "*one normalizes time series only across columns to keep each feature's true information*" or otherwise and why is not an implementation question but a methodological one (implementation is about *how* to do it). Plus, the related code must reside in the question itself, and not in an external repo - please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (it is not even clear *where exactly* in the linked code the relevant piece is - pls see why [a wall of code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)).

Comment: Thank you for clearing!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure either but they do transpose in forward function : x = x.transpose(1, 2) of the MLP class. Thus, it seemed to me that they normalise over time for each feature.